# What kind of gloves should I use to change a projector lamp?

Tags: replacement, lamp, projector

I have an Epson 9300 projector and the lamp is defective. A new original lamp with caddy costs €210, the single lamp without caddy costs €110. I have already opened the caddy and the replacement is not difficult.

So I just want to change the lamp and keep using the caddy.

[image]

I know these lamps are very touch sensitive so I will use gloves.

I have new unused latex gloves here which have white powder on it (talcum?). In the howto videos I've watched they always use cotton gloves. (The manufacturer himself does not give any instructions here, except that the lamp must not be touched with fingers.)

Does latex leave marks so it shouldn't be used for that and should I get some cotton gloves instead?

Comment: At a push, use a handkerchief.

Comment: @Tim The lamp in the caddy is attached with clips, which is difficult to handle with a handkerchief.

Comment: i do not know if talcum powder could be an issue, so i would expect talcum powder to scratch the glass

Comment: @jsotola Talc is at 1 on the Mohs scale of hardness, [fingernails are at about 2.5](https://www.oakton.edu/user/4/billtong/eas100lab/hardness.htm), so talc isn't going to scratch glass, which scores at least 5.

Comment: @AndrewMorton like I said, when in doubt, expect the worst

Comment: @jsotola Yes, definitely. Especially as the talcum powder could also contain corn starch, which I would expect to burn onto the glass and cause hotspots and contribute to early failure. But it won't scratch the glass.

Comment: The actual objective is "don't get gunk on the bulb".  Talc-coated latex fails the test.  You can use a paper towel but that performs poorly on another objective, "don't drop the bulb" which is why gloves are a good idea and why your wooly winter gloves are not.    Anything that provides dexterity and no gunk will do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I wouldn't use anything that could leave a deposit, such as talcum.  If instructions say use cotton gloves, use them. you paid 110 pounds for it, don't chance on risking damaging it by not spending a pound or 2 on cotton gloves.

Comment: Sounds reasonable. (There is no instruction. I watched videos and they use cotton gloves).

Comment: Videos not by the manufacturer, should not be trusted too much.  Would ask the manufacturer for their recommendation.  Quite a few people got hurt from watching videos online.  Cotton gloves do sound correct, but I am just some guy online.

Comment: Spent years doing stage lighting and projection work. Our instructions always aid to use cotton gloves. In a pinch during intermission, I used clean socks from the prop room.

Answer (score 6):

Having spent some years doing this as part of my job, (*i.e.* "professionally") wash hands, dry hands, use a clean, dry paper towel.

If you screw up, wipe it down with isopropyl alcohol on a clean paper towel, wipe it dry rather than leaving a noticeable amount of alcohol, and then let it dry completely anyway before use. But that should not be needed with a merely reasonable level of care and attention to what you are doing.

Never bothered with gloves at all. Never blew a bulb due to skin oils/fingerprints on the bulb. *If* using gloves, absolutely clean cotton, but a paper towel is clean and a lot cheaper.